# Laravel/00webhost Error 404. The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel

**1.**
Uploaded my files to 000webhost. I placed all files from the public folder to **public_html** then I created a folder named **laravel** and there I uploaded all other files. This is the structure of my directory:

> **laravel**
>
> > app
> >
> > bootstrap
> >
> > config
> >
> > ....
>
> **public_html**
>
> > index.html
> >
> > .....

**2.**
In my **index.php** file, I already changed some things to these

> > - require **DIR**.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
> > - $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

**3.**
I also changed the .env file and the database.php in the laravel/config folder

**Problem:**

> I am now able to access the home page of my site, but when I click my links to the other pages error 404 shows up.
>
> > How do I fix this?
> >
> > And how do I access the routes in my api.php ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your includes seem fine.

Be sure you also uploaded the .htaccess file located in /public (in your /public_html). The file name starts with a dot so it's commonly hidden.
The purpose of this file is to indicate Apache how to map URLs to real files (in this case, everything should point to index.php)

Comment: Thanks! There was already an .htaccess file in the public_html folder when I created my site in 000webhost that's why i failed to copy the one in my local public folder. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **index.php** file. Change it as the following:

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

This should solve the problem.