# Laravel-Localization Deployment - The requested URL /en was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

I'm deploying my first laravel app with laravel-localization. Unfortunately, I am currently getting the error,

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /en was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have searched the web trying to find others who had the same problem and see if they had a viable solution for me. I found at least [one](https://www.munderwood.ca/index.php/2016/03/16/testing-routes-with-laravel-localization/#comment-1602), but it looks like he wasn't able to solve it either. I also found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274941/laravel-00webhost-error-404-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server), but neither idea seemed to work.

When I change (in the config/laravellocalization.php file)

```
'hideDefaultLocaleInURL' => false,
```

from False to True

```
'hideDefaultLocaleInURL' => true,
```

I can see the homepage, but only that. All other pages are redirected to the 404 error.

I have also changed the index.php file to reflect my folder structure as the public folder for this site is within a folder within the public_html folder:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../myapp/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

...

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../myapp/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**Note:1** Everything worked on my localhost. There seems to be a problem in deployment.

**Note 2:** As it is currently configured, the site automatically tries to load the www.mysite.com/en version, which makes me think that my changes to the index.php file were correct. Without these changes, I get the error that the page cannot load.

**Note 3:** Here is my current folder structure:

- /home/username
-- mostOfMyFiles
-- public_html
--- nameOfUrl
---- publicFiles

**Note 4:** Regarding routing, here is what I currently have in my web.php file:

```
<?php

    Route::group([
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]
        ], function()
    {
        Route::get('/', function()
        {
            return View::make('welcome');
        });

        Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.about'), function() {
            return View::make('about');
        });

        Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.contact', 'ContactController@getContact'), function() {
            return View::make('contact');
        });

        Route::post(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.contact'),
            ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'ContactController@sendMail']);

    });
```

I have tried adding the 'web' middleware to the group, as seen [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l5-localisation-routing), but this didn't solve the problem either. :(

Note: I am also hosting another site. That is why I have the public files within a folder that has the name of the URL.

Any idea what the problem could be?

I appreciate all ideas, comments, and criticism. :)

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to change the `index.php` file ? I don't think that is a good idea. There are usually variables that you have to change in the `config` files or the `.env` file

Comment: Good question @xperator. This is actually my first time deploying a Laravel site. So, I'm not really sure about that. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4 - which recommended changing the index.php file in the way that I did.

Comment: You know the first thing that comes to my mind is to add a prefix to all your routes. I mean this would usually be the case if your Laravel is in a custom path. Here is a link I found about localization not sure if it's related though https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l5-localisation-routing

Comment: I'm a bit confused since in your Note 2 you're saying you're trying to serve the `mysite.com/en` URL. I thought you want to serve it under a subdirectory, like `mysite.com/my-laravel-app/en`. If you have Laravel in a subdirectory inside `public_html` and you want to serve it with your root path, then all you have to do is to config your web server and tell it to use the `/public_html/my-laravel-app` for the root path.

Comment: The changes you made in your `index.php` file right now is for when you want to serve Laravel from a sub-directory So that when you enter `mysite.com/my-app` in your browser, Laravel would run. It is not supposed to let Laravel run from `mysite.com`

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem.

After some deep research I found solution that work for me.
I am a little bit noob as well with laravel deployment and I dont know why is this such a problem to deploy laravel project on shared hosting, there is literally thousand ways and every time someone said that this isn't the right way, so I dont even know what is actually right way.

I add this block of code in my *"public_html/.htacces"*
        
    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone's looking, in my case it was `route:cache` that caused 'Not found' exception. I completle forgot, that by default you can't use `route:cache` with LaravelLocalization.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for reminding me. I believe you can use `php artisan route:trans:cache` (https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#caching-routes)

Answer (score 0):

> Everything worked on my localhost. There seems to be a problem in deployment.

Are you automatically using cache in deployment? For LaravelLocalization you need to use

```
php artisan route:trans:cache
```

instead of

```
php artisan route:cache
```

See [docs](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/blob/master/CACHING.md) for more.